# Asp.net session: Iframe inception

Tags: asp.net, session, iframe, ms-wopi, excel-online

Bit of a wild question, probably sounds like a design issue, but given the scenario, is the following possible?

A parent window on domain xxxx.com opens a new page with an iframe in it accessing domain yyyy.com, which itself contains an iframe to domain xxxx.com. Can the child iframe access the same asp.net session as what the original parent is using?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if the session is based e.g. on cookies, then the it's applied to any frame/iframe/window within the same browser.